# How to show different attributes in print composer

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer

we have shape file with different attributes wich we want to show in the print composer. The goal is that we open 1 vector layer and the print composer shows 4 different maps (4 attributes). Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Could you clarify a little more please? Are you looking for a 4 different images all based on one single vector layer? And you want each of those images to represent a different attribute?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using QGIS 2.6 to do this which makes it easier to filter out styles based on attributes, as you can see with the checked boxes beside each colour legend. Each legend depicts rules which are set in *Layer Properties* > *Style* > *Rule-based*:

[image: Rule-based]

[image]

First select which attribute(s) you want shown in your first image via the legend:

[image: Select attributes via legend]

Add the map into your Composer:

[image: Add map to composer]

So now you have your first image based on a certain attribute:

[image: Result for one image]

Repeat this by filtering out the attributes via the legend add a new map into the composer until you get 4:

[image: Final result]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is not really what I need to do. The problem is that we have a shape file with different columns whith the necessary atributes. Her is a pic which shows the problem a little bit better.

[image]

Comment: I've edited my post to include how each legend can be represented by a rule-based style. Apologies if I still misundertood, in which case others can advise.

Comment: Your shape file has just one column with the shown attributes. In my file There are different attributes in 4 columns.

Comment: Do you perhaps need help with the filter expression for rule-based styling? Because then you can filter as many attributes for as many columns as you would like. Yes, I did use one column for my example but it can easily be repeated for multiple columns, just depends on what colour you want each attribute to represent.

Comment: I tried this but I think it isn't the solution. Here is a pic (should be the composer result) and a shape file for a better understanding.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mh5vs618fo0pjbw/file.zip?dl=0

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/epyVI.jpg